# What is the name of a "polygon" with piece-wise polynomial boundary?

Tags: geometry, curves, polygons

I would like to know if somebody knows the name of these objects.

Given a set of $N$ vertices $\{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1,\ldots,N}$ (points in $\mathbb{R}^2$) we create a closed curve, defined piece-wise, that goes through all the points, not intersecting itself.

The curve is the union of $N$ polynomial edges

$(x(t),y(t))_i \quad t \in [0,1]$

where $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are polynomials of arbitrary finite degree and such that:

$(x(0),y(0))_i = (x_i,y_i)$

$(x(1),y(1))_i = (x_{i+1},y_{i+1})$

with $N+1 = 1$

Comment: a piecewise algebraic curve ?

Comment: well, that doesn't make refernece to the fact that is closed and simple, i.e. it is a polygon with "polynomial edges", kind of a Bezier, but I guess more general.

Comment: a closed piecewise algebraic curve being the boundary of a simply connected open set

Comment: that is a description rather than a name! Shall I assume there is no name for these objects?

Comment: those kind of polygons in Riemann surfaces have a name : http://star-www.st-and.ac.uk/~fv/webnotes/derive1.gif

Comment: that looks like a spherical triangle